# Web: Hero image [background-image of a div] not showing

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to add a background-image to a div at the top of the webpage and i want it to be responsive as well. i got the code for a hero image from w3school and i did it exactly as shown but still the image doesn't show up. i'm 100% sure that the path for the image is correct as i've used it multiple times on the same page and it works just fine. i'll provide all the info below, any hep would be hugely appreciated.

**Html:**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Kendrick &#128293;</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="body-container">
            <div class="navbar">
                <a href="index.html">Kendrick Lamar</a>
            </div>
        
            <div class="kendrick"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
@viewport {
    width: device-width ;
    zoom: 1.0 ;
}

html, body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #fdfcfa;
}

.body-container {
    min-height: 100%;
}

.navbar{
    height: auto;
    background-color: #1c2120;
}

.navbar a{
    color: #FBFBFB;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 3.5em; 
    font-family: fantasy;
}

.kendrick {
    background-image: url("/images/kendrick!.jpg");
    height: 50%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
```

[image: the folder where the html and css files are]

[image: images folder]

Comment: its only happen for `/kendrick!.jpg` ? whats about for `/kendrick.jpg` ?

Comment: give `.kendrick` a fixed height (200px for example) and see if that works.

Comment: @STA the issue is with background-image because if i use <img> it works just fine but i have trouble making that responsive, and i DO want to use background-image i just don't understand why it's not working.

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul i made .kendrick have a fixed height of the image (640px) the image didn't show up but the space was applied, there's a 640px gap between the nav bar the the rest of the page.

Comment: ok, now can you try inspecting the gap and look at the CSS (or HTML) and see if there is something wrong?

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul There isn't much to the html for something to be wrong `<div class="kendrick></div>`.....same with the css....it's just background-image and some styling.

Comment: i think this is for width and height, give `height:200px; width:1200px;` and check

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul it should also be noted that background-image doesn't work even if i use a link to an image online.

Comment: I tried your code, the background is showing after removing the `/` at the beginning of image url.

Comment: It's not working with online image path as well? That's odd . . . because I just tried with your same code and path and it worked. 

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul i removed the `/` and it WORKED! Thank you so much!

Comment: Yay! Glad to help ‍♀️